# Report Viewer Table Sum not calculating decimal places

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Hi I am trying to sum up a table column in report viewer and for some reason it is not calculating the decimal places? So for example 13.50 + 13.00 is returning 26.00.

Any Ideas?

```
=SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)
```

Comment: Did you try to format the sum field to display decimal value.

Comment: Thanks, I had to rebind my report vierwer